# How to check if a video is done playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I want to detect if the method of an object is called.

I have a video player in my page and when it is done playing, I want to show some contents.

For example:

```
function videoSet(){
    var instance = this;
    this.video   = $('#video')
    this.video.bind("ended", function() {
        instance.endVideo()
    });
}

videoSet.prototype.endVideo = function(){
    $('#test1').css('visibility','visible');
}

//more methods...        

function main(){
    this.init();
}

main.prototype.init = function(){
    this.video = new videoSet() //init an video object.
    // more code...
    //I need to know if the video is ended...
}

var mainObj = new main();
```

Inside my `endVideo` method, I have  `$('#test1').css('visibility','visible');` but I have so much code in my `main` object and I want to be able to detect if the video has ended in my `main` object.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple eventListeners on DOM objects...

```
var Video = function () { this.video = document.querySelector("#my-video"); };

var Main = function () {
    var myVideo = new Video();

    myVideo.video.addEventListener("ended", function () { console.log("It's over!"); });

    myVideo.video.addEventListener("ended", function () {
        console.log("Play something else.");
    });
};

Main();
```

There's nothing stopping you from adding an event-listener to the object from inside of `main`.

Moreover, this leads to custom event systems -- Publisher/Subscriber or Observer or "Emitters".
If you can implement one of these, on an object, then your object can create/fire custom events, and pass custom data, and any time you have access to that object, you can subscribe (as long as you know what the events are called, and how to handle the data you will get back).

For example, you might want to have a video-playing system that loads the next film (or a countdown screen, until the next film, et cetera, for continuous playback, with a playlist that highlights the current film).

```
var VideoPlayer = function (id) {
    var player = this;
    player.video = document.getElementById(id);
    // attach an emitter-system with "on", "off" and "emit", or whatever you choose
    addEmitter(player);
    player.load = function (video) { player.video.src = video.src; };

    player.init = function () {
        player.video.addEventListener("ended", function () {
            // fire custom-event
            player.emit("video-ended");
        });
        player.video.addEventListener("canplay", function () {
            // auto-play video, fire event
            player.video.play();
            player.emit("video-playing");
        });
    };
},


VideoPlaylist = function (id, videos) {
    var playlist = this;
    playlist.root = document.getElementById(id);
    playlist.videos = videos;
    playlist.addVideo = function (video) { /* attach each video to the root */ };
    playlist.currentVideoIndex = 0;
    playlist.currentVideo = playlist.videos[playlist.currentVideoIndex];
    playlist.select = function (i) {
        playlist.currentVideoIndex = i;
        playlist.currentVideo = playlist.videos[i];

        // fire a custom event
        playlist.emit("load-video", playlist.currentVideo);
    };
    playlist.nextVideo = function () {
        var i = (playlist.currentVideoIndex + 1) % playlist.videos.length; // loops
        playlist.select(i);
    };
    addEmitter(playlist);
};


var Main = function () {
    var video_player   = new VideoPlayer("my-player"),
        video_playlist = new VideoPlaylist("my-playlist", [{ src : "...", title : "A" }, { src : "...", title : "B" }]);

    video_player.on("video-ended",  video_playlist.next);
    video_playlist.on("load-video", video_player.load  );

    // add another listener for another component, to handle on-screen controls
    video_player.on("video-playing", video_controller.show_playing);


    // add another listener for another component, to display the data about the video
    video_playlist.on("load-video", video_description.display);
    // add another listener for another component to load comments
    video_playlist.on("load-video", video_comments.load);
};

Main();
```

This isn't a particularly Java-like way of writing programs, but JavaScript isn't particularly Java-like (though you can make it look similar).

You'll notice that inside of the `Main` function all I'm doing is wiring behaviours together, rather than writing out custom logic.

Of course, you can take this way further...

...and I haven't shown you how my emitter is made, but they're not hard to make, either.
Publisher/Subscriber or Observer or Emitter implementations are great practice for JS (and very easy in JS compared to other languages).

But as you can see, with a little thinking, this is a really simple and versatile way of dispatching code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ended flag in the videoSet object like

```
function videoSet() {
    var instance = this;
    this.ended=false;
    this.video = $('#video')
    this.video.bind("ended", function () {
        instance.endVideo()
    });
}

videoSet.prototype.endVideo = function () {
    $('#test1').css('visibility', 'visible');
    this.ended=true;
}
videoSet.prototype.isEnded = function () {
    return this.ended;
}

//more methods...        

function main() {
    this.init();
    //later
    if(myVideoSet.isEnded()){
        console.log('completed')
    }
}
```